# Laravel firstOrNew usage of like operator

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So when I use firstOrNew laravel makes a query on the database like this:

```
SELECT * FROM field_normalizer` where (`supplier` = 'supplier' and `column` = 'column' and `original_value` = 'original_value') limit 1
```

What I want is to do the same query but instead of using equal operator I want to use like operator. Is that possible?

Comment: Extremely possible. But you don't show your Laravel query, so I'll just say `->where('column', 'LIKE', "%$value%")`

Comment: So this cant be done using firstOrNew ?

Comment: Sure it can, you just need to add the where clause to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with firstOrNew as per below code:

```
// Retrieve by name, or instantiate with the name, delayed, and arrival_time attributes...
$FieldNormalizer = FieldNormalizer::firstOrNew(
    [['supplier','LIKE',$supplier],['column','LIKE',$column],['original_value','LIKE',$original_value]],
    ['supplier' => $supplier, 'column' => $column, 'original_value' => $original_value]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get LIKE operator with multiple AND condition in eloquent Laravel

```
$data = DB::table('field_normalizer')
        ->where([['supplier','LIKE',$supplier],['column','LIKE',$column],['original_value','LIKE',$original_value]])
        ->get()
        ->first();
```

I hope it'll be helpful to you

Comment: I find a way to do want I want but I am wondering if this can be done with firstOrNew functions